# Format Code CTRL + ALT + I in PhpStorm not like CTRL + SHIFT + F in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, format, phpstorm

I am a beginner in PhpStorm. I want to format code in PhpStorm like Eclipse. I had used Ctrl + Alt + I to format code but it seem not be that I want (seem like CTRL + SHIFT + F in Eclipse). I searched many answer in here but not success. Here is my code before format:

```php
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
}
    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
}
$this->set(’post’, $post);
}
```

And here is my code after format by Ctrl + Alt + I

```php
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
}
    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
}
    $this->set(’post’, $post);
}
```

I hope it look like:

```php
public function view($id = null) {
    if (!$id) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
    }
    $post = $this->Post->findById($id);
    if (!$post) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__(’Invalid post’));
    }
    $this->set(’post’, $post);
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Try resetting your Code Style to `Default` one. Your code sample reformats just fine here on few bundled presets I have tried (`Set From` functionality)